# Update property of relationship using spring data neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am currently working on creating a web crawler that uses neo4j to store each page's content.  Along with storing content, neo4j is also being used to store links between pages, which will later be used to calculate a page rank.

I am using spring-data-neo4j 4.1.12.RELEASE and have run into an issue when I try to update the relationship between two nodes.  Here is all relevant code.

## Domains

**WebPage (Node)**

```
@NodeEntity
public class WebPage {
    @GraphId 
    private Long nodeId;

    private String url;

    @Relationship(type = "LINKED_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Link> outgoingLinks = new HashSet<>();

    public WebPage() {}

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public WebPage setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "LINKED_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Link> getOutgoingLinks() {
        return outgoingLinks;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "LINKED_TO", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    public void setOutgoingLinks(Set<Link> outgoingLinks) {
        this.outgoingLinks = outgoingLinks;
    }


    public void addOutgoingLink(WebPage linkedWebPage, String anchor) {
        Link outgoingLink = new Link(this, linkedWebPage, anchor);
        outgoingLinks.remove(outgoingLink);
        outgoingLinks.add(outgoingLink);
    }
}
```

**Link (Relationship)**

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "LINKED_TO")
public class Link {
    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @StartNode
    private WebPage sourceWebPage;
    @EndNode
    private WebPage linkWebPage;

    @Property
    private String anchor;

    public Link() {}

    public Link(WebPage sourceWebPage, WebPage linkWebPage, String anchor) {
        this.sourceWebPage = sourceWebPage;
        this.linkWebPage = linkWebPage;
        this.anchor = anchor;
    }    

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((linkWebPage == null) ? 0 : linkWebPage.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((sourceWebPage == null) ? 0 : sourceWebPage.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Link other = (Link) obj;
        if (linkWebPage == null) {
            if (other.linkWebPage != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!linkWebPage.equals(other.linkWebPage))
            return false;
        if (sourceWebPage == null) {
            if (other.sourceWebPage != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sourceWebPage.equals(other.sourceWebPage))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Link [sourceWebPage=" + sourceWebPage + ", linkWebPage=" + linkWebPage
                        + ", anchor=" + anchor + "]";
    }

}
```

## Repository

```
@Repository
public interface WebPageRepository extends GraphRepository<WebPage>{
    WebPage findByUrl(@Param("url") String url);
}
```

## Test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    WebPage sourceWebPage = webPageRepository.findByUrl("http://www.test.com/");
    if (sourceWebPage == null) {
        sourceWebPage = new WebPage().setUrl("http://www.test.com/");
    }
    WebPage linkedWebPage = webPageRepository.findByUrl("http://www.example.com/");
    if (linkedWebPage == null) {
        linkedWebPage = new WebPage().setUrl("http://www.example.com/");
    }

    String anchor = "test";
    sourceWebPage.addOutgoingLink(linkedWebPage, anchor);
    webPageRepository.save(sourceWebPage); 
}
```

**Note**

The equals and hashCode were overridden on the Link domain so that it only uses the source WebPage and the link WebPage to determine equality.  I did this because I did not want to create multiple Links between two WebPages.  So if a WebPage has multiple links to another WebPage, all of the anchors are collected under one Link.

**Issue**

In the test I am creating/finding two WebPages and then creating/updating the Link between the two.  Here is the relevant code (from above) that I am using to update a Link.

```
public void addOutgoingLink(WebPage linkedWebPage, String anchor) {
    Link outgoingLink = new Link(this, linkedWebPage, anchor);
    outgoingLinks.remove(outgoingLink);
    outgoingLinks.add(outgoingLink);
}
```

The issue is that the relationship will be created on the first test, but then deleted on the second test.  This creating and deleting cycle will continue indefinitely.

Here is an example of the runs, starting with no data in database.

Run #1

[image: Run #1]

Run #2

[image: Run #2]

Run #3, same as #1

Run #4, same as #2

Is there a better way to update a relationship?  From my reading, it seems that updating a relationship via the NodeEntity is preferred because using the @Query syntax can cause synchronization issues with the data.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Matt